# How can I set access scopes for my application using the Uber Developer dashboard?

Tags: asp.net, uber-api

I registered my application on Uber Developer Dashboard (server Asp.NET application). In the Auth tab of Dashboard I found the parameters for authorization: `Client ID`, `Client Secret`. Using `OAuth2` I successfully received authorization code in `ASP.Net` `MVC` Controller in `VS2017` by redirect link. 
I use `Uber C# SDK` (https://github.com/timothyclifford/uber-csharp-sdk) 
and run applications on localhost use `ngrok`. When I try to request an access  token, then I get an error. In Visual Studio displayed status

> "Waiting for Activation"

[VS status error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mXA37.jpg)

If you make a request through Postman, then I get this answer

[Postman error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zYxeO.jpg)

In Dashboard I see two message:

Message 1 :

> "Please reach out to your Uber Business Development representative for
>   server token access."

Message 2 :

> "Your application currently does not have access to any scopes. Please
>   contact your Uber Business Development representative or Uber point of
>   contact to request access."

[Dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PHWQn.jpg)

I can assume that the problem is related to the scopes, but I don’t understand how to specify this scopes. I do not need to make requests on behalf of the user, I want make requests from the application account. Also now I can't fill the fields  redirect URI and a privacy policy URL in the Settings tab because the project is under development

How do I set up an application account to get a token? Maybe I'm making a wrong request?

Comment: Any updates? I'm struggling with a similar issue

Comment: Hi. Unfortunately, there are no changes.  I wrote on Google Groups, on Twitter, but no one answered

Comment: tweeted here if anyone wants to help like it to hopefully get attention: https://twitter.com/mredig/status/1183969089754144769?s=20

Comment: any luck with this?

Comment: Do you have any news?